GrowlVoice Mac OS - Anyway to get app to work again or similar suggestions?
This was the most amazing app IMO and so sad no longer available.
Is there any workaround to get to function or anything else out there similar?

Since that API may have been gone for about a decade, here are 5 tips to edit this post if no one has suggestions based on understanding how you used to use that app. Is your carrier still Google Voice?

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
